# Deleting table entries based on criteria in another table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We want to be able to delete entries from a MySQL table, based on deletion criteria set in another table.  Let me explain with an example.
I have two tables defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE base_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  f1 VARCHAR(8),
  f2 VARCHAR(8),
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE del_criteria_tbl
(
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  f3 VARCHAR(8),
  f4 VARCHAR(8),
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

`base_tbl` has the data and `del_criteria_tbl` has the criteria for deleting entries from `base_tbl`.

I populate the tables as follows:

```
INSERT INTO base_tbl(f1, f2) VALUES ('ABC', '123C57'),
('ABC', '532B49'), ('DEF', '397F45'),
('DEF', '684G65'), ('GHI', '793A86'),
('GHI', '541H32');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO del_criteria_tbl(f3, f4) VALUES ('ABC', '532B49'),
('ABC', '813E89'), ('DEF', '397F45'),
('GHI', '541H32');
```

Obviously:

```
mysql>SELECT * FROM base_tbl;
+----+------+--------+
| id | f1   | f2     |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ABC  | 123C57 |
|  2 | ABC  | 532B49 |
|  3 | DEF  | 397F45 |
|  4 | DEF  | 684G65 |
|  5 | GHI  | 793A86 |
|  6 | GHI  | 541H32 |
+----+------+--------+


mysql>SELECT * FROM del_criteria_tbl;
+----+------+--------+
| id | f3   | f4     |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ABC  | 532B49 |
|  2 | ABC  | 813E89 |
|  3 | DEF  | 397F45 |
|  4 | GHI  | 541H32 |
+----+------+--------+
```

---

I would like to define a succinct and efficient SQL operation that executes the following pseudo-SQL logic:

```
DELETE FROM base_tbl WHERE base_tbl.f1 = del_criteria_tbl.f3 AND base_tbl.f2 = del_criteria_tbl.f4
```

After the operation is executed, `SELECT * FROM base_tbl` should yield:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | f1   | f2     |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | ABC  | 123C57 |
|  4 | DEF  | 684G65 |
|  5 | GHI  | 793A86 |
+----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is using **IN** clause in the following way:

```
DELETE FROM base_tbl 
WHERE (f1, f2) in (select f3, f4 from del_criteria_tbl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MYSQL specific construction like:

```
DELETE a.*
FROM base_tbl a
JOIN  del_criteria_tbl b
    ON a.f1 = b.f3
    AND a.f2 = b.f4
```

or use a standard variant:

```
DELETE 
FROM base_tbl a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM  del_criteria_tbl b
    WHERE a.f1 = b.f3
    AND a.f2 = b.f4
)
```